# View API Response as Text instead of json

Tags: python, api, sqlite, flask, flask-restful

My Python Code :

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Resource, Api, reqparse
import sqlite3

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

class Data(Resource):
    def get(self):
        connection = sqlite3.connect('testing.sqlite')
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        parser = reqparse.RequestParser()  # initialize
        parser.add_argument('n', required=True)  # add args
        args = parser.parse_args()  # parse arguments to dictionary
        n = int(args['n'])
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE num = ?", (n, ))
        data = cursor.fetchone()
        return data[1], 200

api.add_resource(Data, '/')  # add endpoints

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)  # run our Flask app
```

Contents of testing.sqlite :

Table is created with `CREATE TABLE mytable (num integer primary key autoincrement unique, content text)`.

[Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cGL1W.png) to see the contents of testing.sqlite as an image.

What this code does is, It import flask, flask_restful and sqlite and initializes a flask application. Creates an API, when it receives a GET Request, it connects to the testing.sqlite file, creates a cursor, initializes a url parameter parser, makes a required argument n, which lets us choose which row's content we want. Then it queries the testing.sqlite file, selects data from the table where num is the requested n (from the url's parameters), fetches the data and returns the second item in the list which is returned, which is the contents and gives a 200 response status code.

The response it gives is this:

```
"Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.\nDeleniti placeat beatae, autem explicabo, voluptatem nisi\nnatus aspernatur tempora voluptatibus animi delectus earum \nveritatis dolore nam, voluptas quibusdam itaque repudiandae. \nTenetur."
```

What I expect it to give as response is this:

```
Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
Deleniti placeat beatae, autem explicabo, voluptatem nisi
natus aspernatur tempora voluptatibus animi delectus earum 
veritatis dolore nam, voluptas quibusdam itaque repudiandae. 
Tenetur.
```

Please help me figure out how to do that.
Thanks.

Comment: The response you get is not json. It is what you expect it to be with the line breaks where they should be.

Comment: @forpas In Chrome Developer tools in Network tab, Under Response Headers, I see that Content-Type: application/json. I don't know if it is json or something else.